# how to generate custom gridlines on dygraph with a certain scale

Tags: dygraphs, gridlines

I've enjoyed using dygraph to plot data from an ECG report. However, I'd like to have additional gridlines in the graph generated so that it is more understandable to an actual doctor or some specialized person. The gridlines could be on custom scales that give out squares of particular sizes, like the one we see in regular ECG reports. I couldn't find anything useful in the documentation for this. Hence, stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I happened to use `pixelsPerLabel` option to scale the grids.